# iOS app behavior based on device's age setting?

Tags: ios, settings, restrictions

Is it possible to modify an iOS app's behavior based on the device's General > Restrictions > Apps setting?

That is: Suppose the device is set to 4+. (And suppose my app is rated 4+ so that it still shows up.) Can my app run, but withhold certain content, refuse to change certain internal settings, etc.?